# Using empty struct properly with CGO

Tags: go, cgo

Working with [gssapi.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/MITKerberosShim/MITKerberosShim-54/Kerberos/gssapi.h)

```
struct gss_name_struct;
typedef struct gss_name_struct * gss_name_t;
```

I am trying to figure out how to properly initialize a variable containing this by

```
var output_name C.gss_name_t = &C.struct_gss_name_struct{}
```

But the functions like [gss_import_name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2744.html#section-5.16) act like if I was passing null pointer to them. What is the correct way to properly initialize and use these empty structs with CGO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go's strict typing makes typedefs a pain to work with. The best way to make your Go look clear is to write a small wrapper function in C to build the struct exactly how you want it. In this case though, go is using a zero-length byte array for an empty C struct, which you can verify below. You can declare it directly in go, and convert it when necessary.

Since C isn't strict with types, using type inference is often the easiest way to assign the type that Go expects. There's also a trick using the cgo tool to show the type declarations you need. Using `go tool cgo -godefs filename.go` will output the cgo definitions for your types. As you see though, the go equivalent types could get a little messy.

```
// statement in the original .go file
//var output_name C.gss_name_t = &C.struct_gss_name_struct{}

// output from cgo -godefs
// var output_name *[0]byte = &[0]byte{}

// or more succinctly
output_name := &[0]byte{}

// output_name can be converted directly to a C.gss_name_t
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", output_name)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", C.gss_name_t(output_name))
```

Comment: This indeed works. As a note though, printing the [0]byte is not very productive (doesn't really print anything). Not a problem, gssapi has C functions for extracting string representations. I just thought I would mention so that no one else gets confused.